# Separate AUTH_USER_MODEL for Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

The Django-Project contains a REST-API, based on TokenAuthentication and a Web Login to the Backend with the Django Auth User.

**The Problem is**: I found no way to specify two different `AUTH_USER_MODEL'S` for each authentication individually.

For the REST-API users, I defined a Custom User Model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = ....
    ....
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'id'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

In the settings I added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.User'`, so that the rest_framework Token authentication references to the right user model.

But when enabling the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` for the Web-Backend, this also uses the `backend.User`model for authentication. But it should use the django built in user model.

How can I specify a second user model specifically for either the rest framework api or for the django.contrib.auth.views?

Comment: Why do you want to have two different users model in your project? Ideally, one project should have only one user model to identify an person/entity.

Comment: Well, the API Users are completely separate (no password etc.) and I don't won't them to get mixed up with the management user's who can only access the management web interface. Should I probably set up a second django project for that stuff?

Comment: You dont need different user model for this. You just needs to set appropriate permissions.

Comment: @RajeshKaushik, there are a lot of situations when alternative user model needed. Legacy systems, distributed systems.